# Error [BAN_RESOLVE_ID]: Couldn't resolve the user ID to unban

Tags: javascript, command, discord.js

I am trying to create my own discord bot and creating an unban command now. My code is below. I banned a friend and tried to unban by typing `-unban 271375814384287744 testing`. It then gives me an error saying `Error [BAN_RESOLVE_ID]: Couldn't resolve the user ID to unban.` Any help would be appreciated.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#39de33')

module.exports = {
  name: 'unban',
  description: "This unbans a user",
  execute(message, args){
      if (message.member.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS")){
          if (!isNaN(args[0])) {
            const bannedMember =  client.users.fetch(args[0]);
            var reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
            if(!reason) {
              reason = "No reason given!"
            }
            if (bannedMember) {
              bannedMember
                message.guild.members.unban(bannedMember, reason)
                .then(() => {
                  embed.setDescription(`Successfully unbanned **${user.tag}**`);
                  message.channel.send(embed);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  embed.setDescription('I was unable to unban the member');
                  message.channel.send(embed);
                  console.error(err);
                });
            } else {
              embed.setDescription("That user isn't in this guild!");
              message.channel.send(embed);
            }
          } else {
            embed.setDescription("You need to provide an user ID to unban");
            message.channel.send(embed);
          }
      } else {
        embed.setDescription("You do not have `BAN_MEMBERS` permissions to unban this member");
        message.channel.send(embed);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe show the args you are passing and check that the ID that is being passed actually exists. The error message seems pretty clear. Discord couldn't find the userId to ban

Comment: Yes I tried it again, banning a friend of mine and trying to unban by coping his ID. It keeps saying "I was unable to unban the member"

Answer (score 1):

I tried this out and got the same error.

```js
Promise {
  <rejected> Error [BAN_RESOLVE_ID]: Couldn't resolve the user ID to unban.
      at GuildMemberManager.unban (/home/kayuimineko/Arc-Neko/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/GuildMemberManager.js:240:36)
      at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/kayuimineko/Arc-Neko/cmdhandler/eval.js:49:26), <anonymous>:1:23)
      at /home/kayuimineko/Arc-Neko/cmdhandler/eval.js:49:26
      at /home/kayuimineko/Arc-Neko/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4838:16
      at /home/kayuimineko/Arc-Neko/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4838:16
      at /home/kayuimineko/Arc-Neko/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
      at /home/kayuimineko/Arc-Neko/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4861:21
      at /home/kayuimineko/Arc-Neko/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4407:11
      at /home/kayuimineko/Arc-Neko/node_modules/kareem/index.js:135:16
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
    [Symbol(code)]: 'BAN_RESOLVE_ID'
  }
}
```

While running

```js
message.guild.members.unban(client.users.fetch(config.admin.owner.id), "reason")
// Ignore the config part it's fine
```

---

Turns out, you should just unban the people by their IDs instead of their user property.
So, to unban the banned member use this code instead:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#39de33')

module.exports = {
  name: 'unban',
  description: "This unbans a user",
  execute(message, args){
      if (message.member.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS")){
          if (!isNaN(args[0])) {
            const bannedMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) // Get the `member` property instead to recall later.
            var reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
            if(!reason) {
              reason = "No reason given!"
            }
            if (bannedMember) {
              bannedMember
                message.guild.members.unban(bannedMember.id, reason)
                .then(() => {
                  embed.setDescription(`Successfully unbanned **${bannedMember.user.tag}**`); // `user` is undefined.
                  message.channel.send(embed);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  embed.setDescription('I was unable to unban the member');
                  message.channel.send(embed);
                  console.error(err);
                });
            } else {
              embed.setDescription("That user isn't in this guild!");
              message.channel.send(embed);
            }
          } else {
            embed.setDescription("You need to provide an user ID to unban");
            message.channel.send(embed);
          }
      } else {
        embed.setDescription("You do not have `BAN_MEMBERS` permissions to unban this member");
        message.channel.send(embed);
      }
  }
}
```