# (node:11197) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Couldn't resolve the user ID to unban

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get the Discord username of the person banned in the unban script, but it doesn't work. I tried all kinds of things, but could you help?

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    if (!message.guild) {
        const ozelmesajuyari = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor(0xff0000)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
            .addField(":warning: Uyarı :warning:", "`unban` adlı komutu özel mesajlarda kullanamazsın.");
        return message.author.sendEmbed(ozelmesajuyari);
    }
    let guild = message.guild;
    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    client.unbanReason = reason;
    client.unbanAuth = message.author;
    let user = client.users.fetch(args[0]);
    let modlog = guild.channels.find("name", "bot-log");
    if (!modlog) return message.reply("`bot-log` kanalını bulamıyorum.");
    if (reason.length < 1) return message.reply("Ban kaldırma sebebini yazmalısın.");
    if (!user) return message.reply("Banı kaldırılacak kişinin ID numarasını yazmalısın.").catch(console.error);
    message.guild.unban(user);

    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0x00ae86)
        .setTimestamp()
        .addField("Eylem:", "Ban kaldırma")
        .addField("Kullanıcı:", `${user.name}#${user.discriminator} (${user.id})`)
        .addField("Yetkili:", `${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)
        .addField("Sebep", reason);
    return guild.channels.get(modlog.id).send(embed);
};

exports.conf = {
    enabled: true,
    guildOnly: true,
    aliases: [],
    permLevel: 4,
};

exports.help = {
    name: "unban",
    description: "İstediğiniz kişinin banını kaldırır.",
    usage: "unban [kullanıcı] [sebep]",
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error \[BAN\_RESOLVE\_ID\]: Couldn't resolve the user ID to unban](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63709606/error-ban-resolve-id-couldnt-resolve-the-user-id-to-unban)

Answer (score 0):

First off, Welcome to Stack Overflow!

[I believe you'll find an answer to your question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63737737/10521934)
When you have an error, try searching for the error first, as it is likely that you aren't the first person to come across it.

To sum up the linked answer, try unbanning by just the user ID rather than a user object.

Also, ensure that you're using the correct syntax for your discord.js version. It is highly suggested that you migrate to disord.js v12, [see the migration guide.](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html)

---

(Türkçe olarak)

Öncelikle, Stack Overflow'a Hoş Geldiniz!

[Burada sorunuzun cevabını bulacağınıza inanıyorum.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63737737/10521934)
Bir hatayla karşılaştığınızda, muhtemelen ilk karşılaşan kişi siz olmadığınız için önce hatayı aramayı deneyin.

Bağlantılı yanıtı özetlemek için, kullanıcı nesnesi yerine yalnızca kullanıcı kimliğiyle yasağı kaldırmayı deneyin.

Ayrıca, discord.js sürümünüz için doğru sözdizimini kullandığınızdan emin olun. Discord.js v12'ye geçiş yapmanız kesinlikle önerilir, [geçiş kılavuzuna bakın.](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html)